# C# using SOAP with other transport layer than HTTP

Tags: c#, soap

While the SOAP standard is transport layer agnostic, Microsoft in their infinite wisdom decided that all their helper classes shouldn't be, at least not in any obvious, well documented way.

So is there any third party library or some other mechanism (I'm thinking a SOAP aware XML serializer perhaps) which accepts as a parameter a SOAP message (as a string or stream) and returns a meaningful data structure (like a Dictionary or dynamic), or will I have to write this myself?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what other protocol than HTTP do you intend to use SOAP over?

Comment: pop3, telnet, ftp and local file system. Yes I know. :)

Comment: In the SOAP protocol the SOAP operation is usually defined as an HTTP request header: SoapAction. How are you simulating this with for example the local file system?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov you can [Dispatch by Body Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395223%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: You can use TCP and named pipes. Have you looked into that? Do you intend to implement your own transport layers?